# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ when the line tangent to the ellipse in the first quadrant forms a triangle whose area is a minimum given $a+b=1$.

Tags: calculus

The problem has 3 parts to it. First I was asked to find the tangent line to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ in the first quadrant where the area of the triangle formed is a minimum. I found it to be $$\frac{x}{a\sqrt{2}}+\frac{y}{b\sqrt{2}}=1$$ The second part asks me to find the minimum area based from the first part of the question when $a+b=1$. This I found to be $\mbox{Area}=ab=b(1-b)$ since $a+b=1$ implies $a=1-b$. What I'm really puzzled about is the one that asks me to find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which this minimum area occurs. I'm not sure what to do with this. Please help.

P.S. The triangle formed here is the one bounded by the tangent line and the coordinate axes.

Comment: I am not sure, yet for some strange reason, I feel one should look into the special case where a=b=0.5 as by symmetry, this is a circle.

Comment: What do you mean by, "the area of the triangle formed is a minimum?" What triangle? The triangle formed by the major and minor axes and the tangent line?

Comment: This is just calculus 1 where I'm supposed to apply  finding relative extrema. That's why I wasn't really having troubles finding those. Just this part where it asks about possible values of a and b where this minimum area occurs given $a+b=1$ is really hard for me.

Comment: The triangle formed by the tangent line to the ellipse, the y-axis and the x-axis. That's the triangle formed in quadrant 1. I was asked to find the minimum area of this which I found to be equal to $ab$. Since $a+b=1$ I set $a=1-b$ then replaced it to my area to get $(1-b)b$.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put $=1$ to the tangent line equation

Comment: I fixed it already.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write the parametric equations of the ellipse as $P(t) = (a\cos t, b \sin t)$. The tangent line at the point $P(t)$ has equation:
$$
(b \cos t)x + (a \sin t)y = ab
$$ 
This line intersects the $y$-axis where $y = b/ \sin t$ and it intersects the $x$-axis where $x = a/ \cos t$. So, the area of the enclosed triangle is
$$
A(t) = \frac{ab}{2\sin t \cos t} = \frac{ab}{\sin (2t)}
$$
Clearly this has a minimum value of $ab$ when $t = \pi/4$. Setting $t = \pi/4$ in the tangent line equation above gives the same result that you found.

If $a + b = 1$, then the minimum area is $b(1-b)$. If you graph the function $f(b) = b(1-b)$, you will see that it's a "hump" shaped parabola that crosses the horizontal axis at $b=0$ and $b=1$. So, by setting $b$ to a value that's slightly larger than $0$ or slightly less than $1$, you can can make the area as small as you like. So, in some sense, the minimum area is zero (or, more precisely, it can be made arbitrarily small).

Note that the second part of the question is pretty much unrelated to the first part: it just deals with understanding the function $f(b) = b(1-b)$.

Comment: I think I get your point. However, can the area be $0$? or should it be greater than $0$?

Comment: The area can only be zero when $a=0$ and $b=1$, or when $a=1$ and $b=0$. But in these cases, the ellipse collapses, so it's not really an ellipse any more.

Comment: I don't think $a$ or $b$ can be $0$ because in the equation of the tangent line, both $a$ and $b$ are denominators. Am I right?

Comment: I'm only talking of the tangent line because the original equation of the ellipse given to me was $$b^2x^2+a^2y^2=a^2b^2$$

Comment: I think that worrying about the cases $a=0$ or $b=0$ is a waste of time. The point is that $b(1-b)$ can be made as small as you want by a suitable choice of $b$. In more rigorous terms, $\inf\{b(1-b) : 0<b<1\}=0$, but this infimum is never attained.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/tangent-and-normal.aspx#equation-of-tangent-line-to-ellipse-in-different-forms,

the equation of any tangent at P$(a\cos t,b\sin t);0<t<\dfrac\pi2$ is

$$x\cos t/a+y\sin t/b=1$$

$$\iff \dfrac x{a\sec t}+\dfrac y{?}=1$$

We need to minimize $$\dfrac{ab}{\sin2t}\ge ab=a(1-a)$$

which can be made arbitrarily small by making $a\to0^+$ or $a\to1^-$

Answer (score -1):

I  think area asked is between tangent and coordinate axis.

The tangent in 1st quadrant is $y= -mx + \sqrt{(a^2*m^2)+b^2}$  where m>0.
Y intercept of tangent is $\sqrt{(a^2*m^2) +b^2}$ ; 
X intercept is   $\sqrt{(a^2*m^2)+b^2}/m$
Area of triangle with coordinate Axes is $= ((a^2*m^2)+b^2)/2m$ ;

```
  Area = (1/2)(a^2*m+(b^2)/m)>=a*b>=1/4   I.e when m^2 = b^2/a^2
  and a is just greater than 1/2 and his just less than 1/2. In limiting case a and b are approaching towards 1/2.
```

Comment: How do we know $a>\frac{1}{2}$ and $b<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Why didn't you just find the derivative and plug it into m? Please format in Mathjax, I can barely understand what you're trying to say. I reformatted the first part for you

Comment: $$\dfrac{a+1-a}2\ge\sqrt{ab}$$ right?